# Valid date format check Oracle - weird behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

We have been looking into some legacy code and found function that checks if date(VARCHAR2) is passed in the proper format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'. It uses simple construct

```
function IS_CORRECT_TIMESTAMP(P_EVENT_TIMESTAMP varchar2)
    return number is
    V_TIMESTAMP timestamp;
  begin
    select TO_TIMESTAMP(NVL(P_EVENT_TIMESTAMP, '1'),
                        'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
      into V_TIMESTAMP
      from DUAL;
    return 1;
  exception
    when others then
      return - 1;
  end;
```

Problem is, when i pass value for example '22-AUG-13', it does not throw any exception. 
What can be reason of this?

Thanks for ideas.

Comment: Oracle tries (too hard sometimes) to be helpful and [converts strings to dates with some flexibility](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements004.htm#sthref405). You've already been told to use the `FX` modifier to prevent that. Just for info though, with your model `22-AUG-13` becomes `0022-08-13 00:00:00`, which is still valid; if you'd used `RRRR` instead of `YYYY` it would have been `2022-08-13 00:00:00`, which is also valid. Some dates would still fail though, e.g. `22-AUG-99`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `FX` format model modifier can be used to require exact matching between a character string and the format model:

```
select TO_TIMESTAMP(P_EVENT_TIMESTAMP, 'FxYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
  into V_TIMESTAMP
  from DUAL;
```

Moreover, you can prevent context switching by not querying `DUAL` table in order to convert character string to a `timestamp` data type:

```
V_TIMESTAMP := TO_TIMESTAMP(P_EVENT_TIMESTAMP, 'FxYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I did not know about "Fx" directive, very handy